# Dart for Web REST API Login Example

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html, dart-webui

There doesn't seem to be any examples of how to handle a login with a backend rest api with Dart. They all seem to either be a service or firebase. Does anyone know of any good examples of a dart for web login using a backend API? Found this for Flutter https://medium.com/@kashifmin/flutter-login-app-using-rest-api-and-sqflite-b4815aed2149, but didn't know if there was an equivalent for Dart for Web.

Answer (score 1):

Use the dart:html HttpRequest class itself

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-html/HttpRequest-class.html

Web login shouldn't have anything specific for typical GET/POST requests. There are a couple of nice articles you can follow there.